# What plug/voltage/hertz does an Ouya use?

Tags: ouya

An overseas friend has asked what kind of plug an Ouya console uses. I haven't received mine yet, so I don't know. I also need to let them know what kind of voltage/etc it expects. Can anyone who has received their console let me know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://ouyaforum.com/showthread.php?864-The-OUYA-Power-cord-Issue) on an Ouya-related message board, it comes with a US-style cord ([A-type plug](http://www.iec.ch/worldplugs/typeA.htm)) but can handle both 110v and 220v.  Relevant quote below

> This isn't really that huge of an issue but I see many of the devs
>   complaining that the consoles were shipping only with US plugs.
>   Although the consoles work with either 110 or 220 volts, they still
>   require you purchase an additional country adapter in or to use it.

Comment: Any idea about the Hz? Based on what you've said so far it's probably the standard American 60 Hz.

Comment: @CuriousBorges: [The vast majority of ~220V countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country) use 50Hz, so if it supports both 110 and 220v, it almost certainly supports both 50 and 60hz as well.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen while you're at it, any thoughts on 230 and 240V? http://www.kropla.com/electric2.htm suggests that it will probably be ok (yeah, wanting someone to post their little ouya manual about now :)

Comment: @CuriousBorges: All of those voltages are within the usual 10% tolerance ranges of the others, so I can't imagine it *not* working. In fact, I would very much expect it to be rated for 100-240V, which covers the complete range of voltages.

Comment: It's _very_ rare for consumer electronics, especially electronics that also support 100-120V, not support 50/60Hz. Japan is split down the middle 50Hz/60Hz @ 100V so anything sold in Japan needs to support both.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig It's 100 _to_ 240 V and 50 _to_ 60 Hz, at least according to the [adaptor text](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/121335/88).

Answer (score 9):

I finally got my OUYA in Switzerland, and it has an (exachangeable) [Europlug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europlug) just as it should have here. To be more precise, here's a photo:

[image: OUYA plug and adapter]

As you can see the Europlug is a small piece that get slipped onto the adaptor, andso I assume that wherever you order your OUYA to, the respective plug piece will be included. Of course if you live somewhere with a rather exotic standard you'll have ask OUYA support or just let them surprise you...

**edit** In reply to @JoeWresching's question about the *other* side of the plug, it's 12 volt DC via [Coaxial power connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_power_connector) (OD 5.50mm, ID 2.50mm, Center Positive) (as per [OUYA's Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouya#Specifications)), so you can probably replace it by your own adaptor if preferred (with the usual warranty void disclaimer).

This is the adaptor's text:

[image: OUYA adaptor]

So with 100-240 V at 50-60 Hz input you should be fine. If you use your own adaptor instead, supply 12 V DC and 1.5 A.

Comment: Zommuter where did you buy it? I bought an Ouya at Game.co.uk (UK) for here in The Netherlands which we use also the Europ standard (2pins). I think i will recieve the UK standard and not the Euro plug.

Comment: @user65337 I got it directly via its Kickstarter. Since you bought it in a UK shop you might indeed receive a UK plug, unless the shop specifically gave you other options. Feel free to ask a [new question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) à la "Where to obtain the small Euro plug front for the OUYA power connector" then...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the ones shipping out now [all have the US plug, regardless of region](http://ouyaforum.com/showthread.php?864-The-OUYA-Power-cord-Issue) but the first post there says the console works with 110 or 220 volts. You'll just need an adapter for whatever plug your region uses. But this is the first, kickstarted production run so that may well change.

Comment: Negative, I got a Kickstarter one with Europlug